# Aurelia conditionally wrapping slots in components

Tags: javascript, aurelia

I'm creating Aurelia components which wrap material-components-web, [cards specifically](https://material.io/components/web/catalog/cards/) right now and am wondering what's the correct way of implementing multiple content sections (actions, etc.).

Slots seem to be the right choice but I cannot just put the actions div on the template at all times, but only if any actions are actually present.

Simply put I need to check if a slot has been defined inside the component template.

```
<template>
    <div class="card">
        <div class="content">
            <slot></slot>
        </div>

        <!-- somehow check here if the slot has been defined -->
        <div class="actions">
            <slot name="actions"></slot>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Out-of-the-box, there is no direct way to do this like a `$slots` property, however you should be able to access slots via the template controller instance itself: `au.controller.view.slots` - the specific slot inside of this array has more information about the slot itself and its children.

[Here](https://gist.run/?id=29a2b60296007b948c82e16ad5c4528b) is an example of an Aurelia application with a modal component (custom modal element). The modal itself has a slot where HTML can be projected inside of it. We have a header, body and footer.

Each predefined slot inside of our custom element should show up inside of a `children` object, where the property name is the name of our slot. If you do not provide a name for a slot (the default slot) the name of it internally is: `__au-default-slot-key__`.

We first check if the slot exists and then we check the length of its children, the `children` array exists inside each slot. If a slot has no HTML projected into it, it will have a children length of zero. This is reliable, because default content defined inside of the slot does not get put into the `children` array, only projected HTML does.

You'll see the work is being done mostly inside of `modal.html`, but pay close attention to `modal.js` where we inject the element reference of the custom element and then access the Aurelia instance using `au` to get to the controller containing our slots itself.

There is one caveat with this approach: you cannot use `if.bind` to conditionally remove HTML inside of your custom element. If you use `if.bind` on a DIV containing a slot, it actually removes its slot reference so it can't be checked. To work around this, just use `show.bind` (as I do in my provided running example).

Comment: Works perfectly, really cool. I'm surprised I couldn't find anything on this topic, everyone seems to use custom attributes to decorate the div with classes which seems like an overkill for something as simple as this.

Comment: Follow up question, probably unrelated: Would you know why [this](https://gist.run/?id=3e6875bac99fb2fb984039b88a873049) doesn't work? I tried to abstract some of the logic to the view-model, because I'll be checking for defined slots in many places. It seems the slotDefined() method is called only once, before attached() happens. I also tried using the @computedFrom('$slots') decorator but now the component doesn't  render at all (no errors), only the defined slots render.

Comment: Went with [this hack](https://gist.run/?id=abf47aa5d72feaeedcd7bced74f2f6f4) for now. It seems .bind cannot call functions so I had to work around it using a getter. Everything works perfectly, again thank you for your help.

Comment: That's awesome @marekpw I would say your solution is perfectly fine. Being able to observe functions is something you can't do because it would require dirty-checking, a getter is definitely the way around this so well done on sorting that out.

Comment: Thanks! It works great (no dirty checking), now I'm thinking of abstracting the code into a decorator and putting it up on npm. I'm new to decorators (never wrote any myself actually) and am just wondering if you think they are the way to go? I use Typescript by the way.

Answer (score 2):

### Use CSS :empty Selector

CSS is the right tool for this job, not Aurelia. The :empty selector will allow you to `display: none` the `div.actions` when the slot isn't populated.

```
.card .actions:empty {
  display: none;
}
```

According to the [:empty selector spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/2018/REC-selectors-3-20181106/) as [explained by CSS-Tricks](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/selectors/e/empty/), white space **will** cause empty to fail to match, so we just need to remove the white space around the slot.

```
<div class="actions"><slot name="actions"></slot></div>
```

Working example here: https://gist.run/?id=040775f06aba5e955afd362ee60863aa

Comment: If this answer was helpful to you, please accept and upvote. If you'd like to help me continue to provide high quality answers, please consider supporting me on Patreon: http://patreon.com/davismj

Answer (score 0):

Here's a method I've put together to detect if any slots have children (excluding HTML comments)

**TypeScript**

```
import { autoinject } from 'aurelia-framework';

@autoinject
export class MyClass {
    private constructor(readonly element: Element) {
    }

    private attached() {
    }

    get hasSlotChildren(): boolean {
        if (!this.element ||
            !(this.element as any).au) {
            return false;
        }
        let childrenCount = 0;
        const slots = (this.element as any).au.controller.view.slots;
        for (let slotName of Object.keys(slots)) {
            const slot = slots[slotName];
            if (slot.children && 
                slot.children.length > 0) {
                for (let child of slot.children) {
                    if (child instanceof Comment) {
                        // Ignore HTML comments
                        continue;
                    }
                    childrenCount++;
                }
            }
        }
        return childrenCount > 0
    }
}
```

**HTML**

```
<template 
    class="my-class" 
    show.bind="hasSlotChildren"
>
    <slot></slot>
</template>
```